# .httpaccess - redirect from http to https protocol only if I'm on the general domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How I can redirect from http to https protocol only if I'm on the general domain (skiped subdomains). I tried using this redirect, but this is redirecting too subdomains.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www?)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```